# how to add an image on UItableviewcell bigger than the cell itself and the tableview

Tags: ios, uitableview

How do I have an image larger than the uitableviewcell itself either as a subview or background view.

I need to show a background image for when the cell is selected.

**edit:
file attached see the highlighted row: the arrow is bigger than the tableview itself and it is bigger than the cell**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In tableView datasource method

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

you can do this :

```
UIImageView * imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"image_background.png"]];
cell.selectedBackgroundView = imageView;
```

When cell is selected its background is set to `imageView`.

Comment: i know how to do the above.....but I want the image to overlap the whole cell and its width bigger than the whole cell

Answer (score 0):

If you are not using any background Image for your `UITableViewCell` than use this `delegate method of`UITableView:`

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willDisplayCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
}
```

If you are using background Image for your `UITableViewCell` than use this in `cellForRowAtIndexPath:`

```
UIImageView *selBGView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"urimage.png"]];
cell.selectedBackgroundView = selBGView;
```